# Directly pass / return image from http response to web interface (streamlit)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, streamlit

I am getting an image (as png) back from an API call. This is then saved as a png file and opened back up to display it in streamlit. This works fine, parts of the code are:

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
import shutil

# in function:
response.raw.decode_content = True
with open("image.png", "wb") as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)

# in streamlit:
image = Image.open("image.png")
st.image(image, caption="This is a caption.")
```

Is there a way to directly return the binary data to the st.image() function? My guess would be, that it's way more performant to just keep the image in memory instead of writing it to a local file. I am imagining something like:

```py
def get_image():
    #post request etc...
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    return response.raw

image = get_image()
st.image(image)
```

I am completely new to handling binary image data in python, so I would appreciate any pointers to helpful resources :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`st.image`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/media/st.image) accepts a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) *object* as a parameter, you can use the logic below :

> `image` : (numpy.ndarray, [numpy.ndarray], **BytesIO**, str, or [str])

```
import streamlit as st
from io import BytesIO
import requests

@st.cache_data
def get_image():
    url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
    r = requests.get(url)
    return BytesIO(r.content)

st.image(get_image(), caption="StackOverflow")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: You might consider decorating your `get_image()` function with `@st.cache_data` to save fetching it repeatedly, see https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching

Comment: Fair enough, answer updated. Thanks @MarkSetchell ;)

Comment: It was just a thought - you already have my up-vote 

Answer (score 1):

If you read the requests [doc](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) you will find:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

Comment: your first comment which suggested using response.content actually worked perfectly with st.image, but thank you for looking it up!